# angularjs ui-grid ui-grid-exporter error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to implement export feature with angularjs ui-gird as explained here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

But I am getting js error something like this:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/unpr?p0=uiGridSelectionConstan…nConstants%20%3C-%20uiGridExporterService%20%3C-%20uiGridExporterDirective`

Here is my code snippet:

`var app = angular.module('CustomerModel', ['ngMessages', 'CommonDirective', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.exporter']);`

`<div ui-grid="Customers" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-exporter></div>`

I think it is related with dependency injection issue but cannot figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  That should work - it's what the tutorials use, and what I use in my code.

It does look like you're missing perhaps uiGridSelection though - perhaps try including that.  I didn't intend to write exporter with a dependency on selection, but perhaps one has crept in.  The tutorial definitely uses selection.

Comment: OK, that's not supposed to be a dependency.  I'll raise an issue and look at it.

Comment: I would like some more help from you, have tried to make the UI Grid responsive, if yes can you let me know how to do the same. Thanks !!

Comment: You can't make it responsive as such, but you can make it resize when the window resizes.  The auto-resize feature is the best bet for doing that.  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing

Comment: But my columns get collapsed when I resize the browser, the actual behavior should be a something like horizontal scroll should appear so all columns are visible and none of them are collapsed or shrink ed.

Comment: If you set your column width using % or * hen they will resize.  If you set fixed width they shouldn't, although there were recent fixes in master in this area so you may need unstable.

Comment: I've fixed today the dependency on selection - it shouldn't have been there.